# Android Out of memory error in creating bitmap for screen shot

Tags: android, bitmap

I created a Bitmap to capture the WebView content.
There is no problem when the size of the content is small.
However, when the size of the content is large, an Out of memory error occurs when creating the bitmap.

Here is my code.

```
    float scale = webView.getScale();
    int webViewHeight = (int)(webView.getContentHeight() * scale);

    //************************************************************
    // An error occurs here.
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), webViewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    webView.draw(canvas);


    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What method should I use to capture Webview of large content?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with other config, e.g. Bitmap.Config.RGB_565. It will decrease size of created bitmap

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The content size may be very large.
So even if use that method, out of memory occurs too.
Can I allocate a bitmap to disk without allocating it to memory?